rectangular random process
We consider a binary waveform that consists of a sequence of impulses with the following properties:

Each impulse has a duration of $T_b$;
The impulses are equiprobable and statistically independent;
The impulses are not synchronized; hence, the start time $t_d$ of the first impulse can be anywhere between 0 and $T_b$;
The symbols '1' are represented by an impulse with amplitude $A$ volts, and the symbols '0' are represented by 0 volts.


I know how to find the autocorrelation for $( \tau < T_b )$ As discussed in this [DSP StackExchange link], which is given by:
$
R_X(\tau) = \frac{A^2}{4} \left(1 + \frac{|\tau|}{T_b}\right)$. The issue arises when calculating the expectation $( E[X(t) X(t + \tau)] )$ for $( \tau > T_b )$, whith the formula $E[\mathcal X(t)\mathcal X(t+\tau)] = E\left[\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathcal B_k p\left({t - \mathcal T_d -kT}\right)\sum_{k^\prime=-\infty}^\infty \mathcal B_{k^\prime} p\left({t+\tau - \mathcal T_d -k^\prime T}\right)\right]$ where the result should be $( \frac{A^2}{4} )$. After this, I need to find the global autocorrelation value, which is given by:
$R_X(\tau) = \frac{A^2}{4} + \frac{A^2}{4}\left(1 + \frac{|\tau|}{T_b}\right)$
I know how to calculate the expectation of $ B_k B_{k'} $, but I am missing how to calculate the expectation of $ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} p(t - \mathcal{T}_d - kT) \sum_{k'=-\infty}^{\infty} p(t + \tau - \mathcal{T}_d - k' T) $.

Sorry, but the link doesn't work

@Hilmar I've re-edited the text

The $x(t)$ in this problem is almost the same as the $x(t)$ in the link that OP has cited: indeed if the signal here is denoted $x_1(t)$ and the other signal $x_2(t)$, then $$x_1(t) = \left(\frac{A+x_2(t)}{2}\right).$$ It is a straightforward calculation to find the autocorrelation  function of the process being considered here from the results on autocorretation presented in the answer to the other question. I vote to close this question as an essentially a duplicate of the other question.
There are also numerous typos in what the OP has written in the question.

@DilipSarwate I knew how to solve it by separating $x_1(t)$ into two forms, I just wanted to understand the direct method.
